# AppEngine datastore entities stats not available. But it works locally.

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an app on appengine. It works fine locally. This morning, I deployed it and it doesn't work properly.
This is the [app link](http://team-app.appspot.com/login), you can user username: qingWANG & password: wang123456 to log in as a teacher. Please forgive its ugly look, because it's just a prototype. When you log in, click reviewAssignment and in the new page you can see the homework students' uploads. You can try to click the score button, and you will see a 500 server error. The weird thing is, the first score button works fine, although it doesn't at the beginning; the others totally do not work.

When I check the datastore admin, it shows this:

[image]

I tested all these pages locally many times. But why does this error happen when I deploy?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me. I am not getting any 500 errors...

Comment: Ahhhh, you're right. #2 and #3 don't. Apologies for the false hope. Button #1 worked for me every time though.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your dashboard and check the logs to see what is going on...

Comment: Thank you. I am closing to the point. But these entities stats not available?

Answer (score 0):

According to the stats page (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/stats)

"To keep the overhead of storing and updating the statistics reasonable, Cloud Datastore progressively drops statistics entities"

So when having lots of namespaces or entities, datastore statistics become unavailable.

Thus at some point sharded counters (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) must be used.

Answer (score -1):

I deployed my app to Server, then I got this situation too.

No matter what I do, I can save an Entity and get it by Key. But I always failed by query it.

Two hours later, magical thing happened. I came back to the console and fresh the data... they are here. Every data I saved into database was there.

... Obviously, you don't need to do anything to fix it. Just let it run a while longer. It will be fixed by itself.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10892951)

Comment: "You don't need to do anything to fix it. Just let it run." ... Is my English so terrible that make  you miss the answer?